# How to tell that this file was created from my app?

Tags: android, algorithm, file

I'm making sound mixer app on Android that user can create a mix, export the mix to mp3 file and upload the mix to server for sharing.

Right now I save all the mixes in a folder that I create on a phone sd card. I filter the files by using mp3 extension for showing on a list within my app, but it can show any files that have the mp3 extension even other mp3 files that I copy to this folder.

If I can't figure this problem out, user will upload any mp3 files from this folder to the server.

Is there any ways that I can mark a file whether it's created from my app?

Ps. I'm open to any suggestions here.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to save the files as mp3 on the device? It might be better to save them with some proprietary file extension, then convert it back to `.mp3` server side if you needed to. Also, you could consider storing the files in internal storage which the user cannot access manually.

Comment: Should I save a file without an extension and store the file in internal storage? but a rooted phone still can access to this directory, can't it?

Comment: There's no bulletproof way to deal with this I'm afraid, things like this can always be broken because there are ways to also decompile APKs and look at the (obfuscated) source code or simply look at the network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that users are uploading mp3's that aren't mixes created by your app?

You can accomplish this (barring intentional user intervention) by storing them in Internal Storage rather than on the SD card.

If they must be stored in external storage, private external storage is available on Android 4.4+.    See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal and scroll down to **Saving files that are app-private**.

There's nothing you can do to stop someone determined from uploading files you don't want to your service, but it doesn't sound like that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'll put my suggestions here.

First idea is to add something to each file's meta data, like the name of your app could go into the composer slot. Then you can [read the metadata](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) on each file before uploading/displaying it.

Of course, users could add that metadata themselves and upload anything to your servers.

Another idea is to use encryption. I don't know which would work best in your app but you could encrypt the file, put a signature in the metadata, name the file with a signature, or something else. Verifying a signature for each file would at least prevent people from casually messing with things.